# How to change methods used through parameters of a method in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing a simple poker game in java and I'm currently working on the player. When required to make the ability to sort the player's deck by suit, value, and rank in deck, I wondered if I could do this all through one method without just using if statements. I learned about java reflections through research, but I'm unsure if it is what I need and it is confusing for me. However, I'm still interested in finding a solution.

So I would like to have method as shown below to simply change how it sorts by changing the parameters.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class BasicPlayer
{
    // instance variables
    Card[] myHand;

    /**
    * Constructor, places 5 cards in player's hand
    */
    public BasicPlayer()
    {
        myHand = new Card[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            myHand[i] = new Card(i);
        }

    }

    /**
    * sort the deck by rank, suit, or value
    */ 
    public void sort(String n)
    {
        Method m = Card.class.getDeclaredMethod("get"+n);
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < 51; j++)
            { 
                // prob not correct, unsure how to invoke method on object 
                // in array
                if (m.invoke(myHand[j]) < m.invoke(myHand[j+1])) 
                {
                    Card t      = myHand[j];
                    myHand[j]   = myHand[j+1];
                    myHand[j+1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to use the [Command Design Pattern](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077569/core-java/java-tip-68--learn-how-to-implement-the-command-pattern-in-java.html) and several `Comparator<Card>`.

Comment: You don't need to use reflection for that. You can create custom Card comparator and sort your Card collection according to the logic in your Comparator - Here's an example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already suggested - using [`Comparator<Card>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is the right way to solve your problem.

Here's a very good introduction tutorial to [Comparator and Comparable](http://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable).

And here's a very thorough design review of how to [design deck of cards in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128398/deck-of-cards-design). It includes Comparator example, as well as other good OOP design points.